# How do I do an aggregate sum in a coredata query?

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I have a core data table with BLOBs in it. I'd like to do a query that does the equivalent of:

```
select sum(length(image)) from tablename;
```

That would return the total size of all the images in the table. Is this possible in core data?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but considering the fact that blob attribute has length method you may try doing the following:

```
[model valueForKeyPath:@"image.@sum.length"];
```